# teleport validateConfigOnDeploy

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, teleport

I am deploying teleport in kubernetes with argocd and I am stuck creating the configmap of the auth-test and proxy-test pods.

only when I put "validateConfigOnDeploy = false" does the deployment happen. but I don't know what this generates, because the documentation doesn't say anything. any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you configure ArgoCD to install the Teleport cluster using the [`teleport-cluster` Helm chart](https://goteleport.com/docs/reference/helm-reference/teleport-cluster/)?

ArgoCD supports installing applications using [Helm charts and specify custom values](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/), so it should be a matter of configuring it.

When using the `teleport-cluster` Helm chart, all the configuration is managed by the chart and you just need to specify the values.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: There we have it deployed using this format. and it fails the same.

apiVersion: v2
name: teleport
description: Teleport Cluster
type: application
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
   - name: teleport-cluster
     version: "13.3.8"
     repository: "https://charts.releases.teleport.dev/"

Comment: Can you please share your configuration?

Comment: teleport-cluster:
  #chartMode: standalone
  clusterName: pepe.com
  proxyListenerMode: multiplex
  
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existingClaimName: ""
    volumeSize: 10Gi

  highAvailability:
    replicaCount: 2

    podDisruptionBudget:
      enabled: true
      minAvailable: 1

  sessionRecording: "node"

  highAvailability:
    replicaCount: 2

    podDisruptionBudget:
      enabled: true
      minAvailable: 1

  sessionRecording: "node"

Comment: Please edit your answer don't ask question either